# How to restore correct permissions after accidental chmod?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I ran `chmod -R 644 /` as user on an AWS EC2 instance.

Now, every time I navigate to a folder or list it, it shows:

```
-bash: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/scripts/initialize: Permission denied
-bash: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/scripts/hook: Permission denied
```

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: this is either how to change permissions after   accidentally lockinf yourself out from doing it,or finding what the old permissions were and restoring them. The latter would be an interesting q

Comment: I was doing `chmod -R 777 ./` but I miss the `.`. And, in the lapse of the moment I tried to fix, without thinking, `chmod -R 644 /`. After I disconnect from ssh I could not connect anymore. Probably mess up with something related to the ssh keys. Because of it was a new instance, I decide to start a fresh new other and be more careful with my words.

Answer (score 0):

Become owner of those files/folders.

```
chown /home/ec2-user/.rvm/scripts/initialize
chown /home/ec2-user/.rvm/scripts/hook
```